# Problems trying to get an id from an eventLlistener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, movieclip

I'm trying to send an id via an event listener to it's listening function. Now this worked before when I created the buttons just using code, but when I decided to use existing movieClips it stopped and I can't work out why.

Here's my button code.

```
private function addButtons(){
        button1 = new ButtonMC();
        //add the buttons
        button1.id = 1;
        button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gameClick, false, 0, true);
        button1.buttonMode = true;
        addChild(button1);
        trace("button1 = "+button1.id);
```

}

the trace finds the button1.id no problem. So ok so far.
When I run this the listener function reports back as 'undefined'. Here is my listener function code. (not all of it.. just the relevant part).

```
private function gameClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
        trace("clicked "+evt.target.id);
        var gameTypeID = evt.target.id;
```

}

This code sits in it's own separate class which generates the start screen. The movieClip buttons are duplicates of an MC in the library which is exporting as ButtonMC. I'm totally stumped as to why this is not working now. When it did work the "generated" buttons where still normal movieClips so I see no difference there. Maybe it's a scope thing, but with all of this code in the same class I can't see why that would be the issue.

Can anyone spot my idiocy and let me know please? Your help as always is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try casting evt.target as a ButtonMC:  trace("clicked " + ButtonMC(evt.target).id); or try using evt.currentTarget.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` property coming from a mouse event refers to the DisplayAsset actually clicked - in this case, some other DisplayAsset *inside* your button. You'll probably notice that the `target`'s `parent` is the button (or the `parent`'s `parent`, etc).

Anyway, use `currentTarget` instead to get the target that had the event added, or set `mouseChildren` as `false` for the button (that way, its children won't capture mouse events themselves).

Comment: That's brilliant.. Thanks to everyone who answered. Using currentTarget worked perfectly. Zeh, you were correct about the eventListener targeting something else in the button. I'd added a blank movieClip underneath the graphic as a hit shape. I had no idea it wouldn't count the whole button as one clip. You learn something new everyday with AS3 it seems.

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would be that the actual shape or sprite that is clicked *within* the ButtonMC instance, is registered as the event.target. You could test this theory and trace getQualifiedClassName(event.target) in your listener. Or you could try the fix right away and add `button1.mouseChildren = false;` to see if it works.